# How to move files using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory?

Tags: android, file

My code renames all .mp3 files (replace 'audio only' with ' '). There are lots of mp3 files I have to download, but anyways, this works fine.

The problem is, how do I move these files to a separate folder? What modifications do I need to make to my existing code?

```
/ getting download folder path for filename fixer
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/");
public static final String[] TARGET_EXTENSIONS = {"mp3"};//target extensions 

class FilenameFixer extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        renameInDir(myDirectory);
        return true;
    }

    private void renameInDir(File dir) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    renameInDir(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();
                    for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                         //(?i) means ignore the case
                        fPath = fPath.replace("audio only", " "); // empty
                    }
                    listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you do now and what you want. Please write a better post first. Dont let us have to look at your code to discover what you do and want. Put all in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: @greenapps Could you explain what is "unclear" in my post?